# How to test if a string variable in Robot Framework is empty?

Tags: string, robotframework, is-empty

How to test if a string variable in Robot Framework is empty?

My first naïve attempt looked like this:

```
Run Keyword If  ${myVar}!=${EMPTY}
```

but it failed:

> Evaluating expression '!=' failed: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing (, line 1)

I then found this [issue](https://github.com/robotframework/robotframework/issues/1795) at Github but it didn't suggest a solution, just that the error message was unclear. An alternative solution was presented [here](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/robotframework-users/XBy6RX12vfA/xPOjcKcOI_wJ):

```
${length}=    Get Length    ${Portfolio_ste}
Run Keyword If    ${length}    Go To Edit Portfolio
```

but is this really the best practice?

(The context is that I use a variable argument list and if a certain variable contains a value something should be done, otherwise just ignore it)

Comment: `Run Keyword If  '${myVar}'!='${EMPTY}' ` wrap your variables in apostrophe

Comment: This will cause parse errors if `${myVar}` contains newline characters. In that case, the proposed solution is appropriate. If you can be sure your string can be parsed, then use the solution presented in @Bryan's answer.

Answer (score 9):

The expression needs to be a valid python expression after variable substitution. Assuming for the moment that `myVar` might be something like the number 42, your expression would end up looking like this after substitution:

```
Run Keyword if  42!=
```

When comparing against the empty string you need to add quotes to guarantee that the expression is a proper python expression after substitution. For example:

```
Run Keyword If  "${myVar}"!="${EMPTY}"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Byran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley)'s answer is good for this specific case but here are also some more general helpful commands to check for empty string:

```
Should Not Be Equal  ${EMPTY}  ${myVar}
Should Not Be Empty  ${myVar}
```

See https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html

Answer (score -1):

Try  [`Get Variable Value`](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Variable%20Value). It solved my problem.

Comment: For those of us who like to see a URL before clicking: https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Get%20Variable%20Value

Comment: you are free to hover over the link before clicking it ;-) Anyway, you answer doesn't solve OP's question: test whether the string is empty (i.e. exists, but contains no characters)